# Wordpress Shopper Header Difficultly

Tags: css, wordpress

I’ve been trying all day to get the header image in wordpress shopper theme to respond correctly. The image is resizeing to it’s screen display  but it’s adjusting either to small or two large.

Is there a css i can use to add different images for different displays. Like can i call for a different header image on displays less than 424px ?

The text overlay is also to dark and can’t be read well . How can I adjust the title text appearance to one with a shadow of some sort. I’m useing shopper theme on wordpress.

for {} screen
{}@media only screen and (max-width:424px){your div css here .img{background-image: url("https://beiiu.store/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Depositphotos_171017402_original-1.jpeg");}}

for {}screen
{}@media only screen and (max-width:800px){your div css here .img{background-image: url("https://beiiu.store/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/688963696-2048x2048.jpg");}}

for {} screen
{}@media only screen and (max-width:1080px){your div css here .img {background-image: url("https://beiiu.store/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Depositphotos_171017402_original-1.jpeg");}}``

Comment: Please provide a sample of the code you are using.

Comment: I'm not using any code for the header at the moment. I'm using the built in header for the theme. I'm going to try the code below.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using 'media', you can change your image according to the screen size like:

```
// for 424px screen
    @media only screen and (max-width:424px){
                   //your div css here
                   .img{
                      background-image: url("first.jpg");
                   }
                }
//for 800px screen
    @media only screen and (max-width:800px){
                   .img{
                      background-image: url("second.jpg");
                   }
                }
    //for 1080px screen
    @media only screen and (max-width:1080px){
                   .img{
                      background-image: url("third.jpg");
                   }
                }
```

Comment: I tried adding the code to additional css and it says 19 errors.

Comment: Link with CSS errors in additional CSS shopper theme. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1deJMYSQSpguwNOuo3OEpDz2JWzyzt5Uf/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Hello, please try by removing the comment sections ("// for 424px screen", etc) and replace the respective required div class name with ".img"